# codeigniter update 1.7 to 2.0 hook error

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I have an error when try upgrade codeigniter 1.7 to 2.X in the hook area

```
$this->CI->load->library('session');
$this->CI->load->model('administrator');
```

Those lines no working in my hook

Here my hook contructor

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Security
{
    private $CI;
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }
```

It's shows error in the library and in the model $this->CI->load->model('name_model');

I was follow the steps in codeigniter but the hooks no working, I'm check the config and everything is supose ok.

The hook not load the model and libraries. And I do not why.

Comment: What's the error?  What does your `hooks.php` config look like?

Comment: $this->CI->load->library('session');
$this->CI->load->model('administrator');

These lines will not work in CI 2.X. Why not work. What can I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upgrade CI from 1.7 to 2.X, you have to follow this complete tutorial.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_200.html

Follow it exact step by, And for your reference in CI 2.X you have to Update your Class extension, means All core classes are now prefixed with CI_. Update Models and Controllers to extend CI_Model and CI_Controller, respectively.

```
$this->CI->load->library('session');
$this->CI->load->model('administrator');
```

These lines will not work in CI 2.X

Comment: Ok thanks for answer but that code is a Hook in system/application/hooks/security/Security.php  actually y have change de controller and model to CI_ the only error is in my hook library.